# Decode data from URL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to get data from an URL using PHP. The data i get from the URL is like this:

`ok {RAH31E telex {Testing1}} {RAH31A telex {Testing1}} {RAH31B telex {Testing1}} {RAH31D telex {Testing1}}`

Explaination:
`ok {SENDER1 TYPE {MESSAGE1}} {SENDER2 TYPE {MESSAGE2}} {SENDER3 TYPE {MESSAGE}} {SENDER4 TYPE {MESSAGE}}`

my Plan is, to get the data to my msql table
`ID | SENDER | TYPE | MESSAGE`

The amount of Messages/ Senders etc is variable. It could be one Message up to 10 messages.

I dont have a clue to get this done.

Comment: Are you sure you cannot get the data in some more usable format? JSON maybe, almost aything woudl be more usable than that

Comment: The Problem is, that i have no access to the structure, it is provided by another website.

Comment: You have a little computer language there in your messages. You'll need to parse your language into its component parts.  Parsers like these are rarely elegant, but who cares? maybe start with `$arrayOfRows = explode( '}} {', $input );` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php  (Your English is fine.)

Comment: Show the complete url your getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that sample does actually match your data, and you can't use another format, you can try parsing it with regex:

```php
$data = 'ok {RAH31E telex {Testing1}} {RAH31A telex {Testing1}} {RAH31B telex {Testing1}} {RAH31D telex {Testing1}}';
$pattern = '({(?<SENDER>[^\s]+?)\s(?<TYPE>[^\s]+?)\s{(?<MESSAGE>[^\s]+?)}})';

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER )){
    foreach($matches as $match){
        echo $match['SENDER'], ':', $match['TYPE'], ':', $match['MESSAGE'], PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/mKYRW

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is working very fine for me!